# iteration being skipped over for some weird reason

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following code...

```
Function PrintArrayAsGrid
{
    param([string[]]$Array,[ValidateRange(1,24)][int]$ColumnCount)

    $GridSplat = @{
        InputObject = $Array|ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{'Value' = $_}
        }
        Property    = 'Value'
    }

    if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ColumnCount'))
    {
        $GridSplat['AutoSize'] = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $GridSplat['Column'] = $ColumnCount
    }

    Format-Wide @GridSplat
}

Function UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
{
    $userInputNotYetValidated = $true
    $userInput = Read-Host "
    Enter AD property name you wish to search with (e.g.: employeeNumber)"

    $userInput = $userInput.Trim()
    Write-Host "you input $userInput"
    Write-Host ""

    [String[]]$validAdProperties = @('SamAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
    'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
    'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
    'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8')

    while ($userInputNotYetValidated)
    {
        If ($validAdProperties -notcontains $userInput)
        {
            Write-Error "Invalid AD Property Name: $userInput"

            PrintArrayAsGrid $validAdProperties 4

            $userInput = Read-Host "    Enter one property name from list above to search with"
            Write-Host "you input $userInput"
            Write-Host ""
        } Else {
            $userInputNotYetValidated = $false
        }
    }
    Write-Output $userInput
}

# Ask user to enter property name in AD to search with
$searchAdPropertyName = UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
```

## Output:

```
        Enter AD property name you wish to search with (e.g.: employeeNumber): asdf
you input asdf

UserInputAdSearchPropertyName : Invalid AD Property Name: asdf
At C:\Scripts\Tests\temp2.ps1:59 char:26
+     $searchAdPropertyName = UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,UserInputAdSearchPropertyName

        Enter one property name from list above to search with:
```

The issue here is it's not printing the list of properties and skipping over the iteration where it calls the function with `PrintArrayAsGrid $validAdProperties 4`

Here is what happens if I add the following lines...

```
            Write-Host 'Found'
            PrintArrayAsGrid $validAdProperties 4
            Write-Host 'Found'
```

## output:

```
            Enter AD property name you wish to search with (e.g.: employeeNumber): asdf
you input asdf

UserInputAdSearchPropertyName : Invalid AD Property Name: asdf
At C:\Scripts\Tests\temp2.ps1:60 char:26
+     $searchAdPropertyName = UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,UserInputAdSearchPropertyName

Found
Found
        Enter one property name from list above to search with:
```

And now, I actually get the table printed out if I add in an exit as follows...

```
            Write-Host 'Found'
            PrintArrayAsGrid $validAdProperties 4
            Write-Host 'Found'
            Exit
```

## Output:

```
PS C:\Tests> .\test1.ps1

                Enter AD property name you wish to search with (e.g.: employeeNumber): asdf
you input asdf

UserInputAdSearchPropertyName : Invalid AD Property Name: asdf
At C:\Tests\test1.ps1:61 char:26
+     $searchAdPropertyName = UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,UserInputAdSearchPropertyName

Found
Found


SamAccountName                msRTCSIP-UserEnabled          msRTCSIP-OptionFlags          msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress
msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer    mail                          msExchMasterAccountSid        homeMDB
proxyaddresses                legacyExchangeDN              lastLogonTimestamp            logonCount
lastLogoff                    lastLogon                     pwdLastSet                    userAccountControl
whenCreated                   whenChanged                   accountExpires                sn
givenName                     displayName                   distinguishedName             initials
l                             st                            street                        title
description                   postalCode                    physicalDeliveryOfficeName    telephoneNumber
facsimileTelephoneNumber      info                          memberOf                      co
department                    company                       streetAddress                 employeeNumber
employeeType                  objectGUID                    employeeID                    homeDirectory
homeDrive                     scriptPath                    objectSid                     userPrincipalName
url                           msDS-SourceObjectDN           manager                       extensionattribute8


PS C:\Tests>
```

## Desired Output:

```
PS C:\Tests> .\test1.ps1

                Enter AD property name you wish to search with (e.g.: employeeNumber): asdf
you input asdf

UserInputAdSearchPropertyName : Invalid AD Property Name: asdf
At C:\Tests\test1.ps1:61 char:26
+     $searchAdPropertyName = UserInputAdSearchPropertyName
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,UserInputAdSearchPropertyName


SamAccountName                msRTCSIP-UserEnabled          msRTCSIP-OptionFlags          msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress
msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer    mail                          msExchMasterAccountSid        homeMDB
proxyaddresses                legacyExchangeDN              lastLogonTimestamp            logonCount
lastLogoff                    lastLogon                     pwdLastSet                    userAccountControl
whenCreated                   whenChanged                   accountExpires                sn
givenName                     displayName                   distinguishedName             initials
l                             st                            street                        title
description                   postalCode                    physicalDeliveryOfficeName    telephoneNumber
facsimileTelephoneNumber      info                          memberOf                      co
department                    company                       streetAddress                 employeeNumber
employeeType                  objectGUID                    employeeID                    homeDirectory
homeDrive                     scriptPath                    objectSid                     userPrincipalName
url                           msDS-SourceObjectDN           manager                       extensionattribute8


        Enter one property name from list above to search with:
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your `Format-Wide @GridSplat` line produces any output? Why do you think it skips anything?

Comment: Also you mix `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` in your code, is it intentional?

Comment: Write-Output is to assign the variable that will be used later for multiple things. Write output is just to write to the window to let the user know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, as was mentioned by Charlie Joynt, Format-Wide is written to a seperate stream that does not get dumped until the script is about to exit, or until `return` or `Write-Output` is called.

Since the parent function is purposely using `Write-Output`, the `Format-Wide` would get stuck in the stream line and have it's value(s) assigned with whatever variable value is being passed through the parent function (as well).

First thing to do is not let Format-Wide enter anything in the stream. To do this, we assign it to a variable. While assigning it to a variable, we want the value to remain in string format. Once this is done, we just write the value out to the host.

To do all this, I just change the line from this:

```
Format-Wide @GridSplat
```

To this:

```
$table = Format-Wide @GridSplat | Out-String
Write-Host $table
```

Comment: You could do it in one statement: `Format-Wide @GridSplat | Out-Host`

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing happens when you have some text being written explicitly back to the host (`Write-Host`) and other text being returned as if the output from a function.

When you invoke a command or expression that returns text (for example) just by calling that function directly (as opposed to assigning the output to a variable or piping to a subsequent command) then this is sent to the "output" stream, much like what you'd get when using `Write-Output` or `return`. In your case, the formatted list of attributes is being included in the output of the function rather than being written out exactly when you want it to be shown.

If you check the value of `$searchAdPropertyName` you will see that it includes both the formatted list of attributes **and** the one attribute name entered at the prompt.

Since the output of `PrintArrayAsGrid` is what you get from the `Format-Wide` cmdlet, it isn't a regular string that you can just write out like others, making this a little trickier. I won't try to fix that in this answer, as I'm aiming at answering the "why is this happening" question!

BTW, you might want to use `Write-Warning` instead of `Write-Error` when someone enters an incorrect attribute name; this will suppress some of the mess you get with a fully-fledged error.

Comment: Wow you are correctly. All I did was remove the Write-Output line and it the grid printed while within the while loop. Weird. I'm used to languages that return only what you tell it to return. I'll have to think of a way around this...

Comment: Have a read of this [ScriptingGuy blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/07/04/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/). It talks about output streams and how `Write-Host` differs.

Comment: So I went through the article, but apparently write-information wasn't added until v5 and I have v3. That is why i get unrecognized cmdlet error. After hours of playing around with the Format-Wide, assigning it to an object, and playing around with the object types, I was able to figure out how to make it print out the table on command (without assigning it to the output from the parent function). I'll write in an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to what you're trying to do is to pop up a dialog box for the user to select the correct attribute. You can do this by passing the array of valid attributes through the Out-GridView cmdlet and assigning the result to your `$userInput` variable. Snippet below:

```
...
Write-Warning "Invalid AD Property Name: $userInput"

$userInput = $validAdProperties | Out-GridView -Passthru
...
```

If you don't mind the list of attributes appearing in another window, then this at least ensures that when an attribute is selected it will definitely be something from your valid list!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not really looking to have the script open up new windows though. If there is a way to make it just print out when it's called, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to define the `$userInput` variable as a parameter and use the `ValidateSet` attribute to ensure that user can only input proper AD property names.

```
function UserInputAdSearchPropertyName 
{
    param(
        [ValidateSet('SamAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
            'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
            'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
            'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8'
            )]
        [string]$userInput
    )

    # rest of function here
}
```

This will allow the user to tab-complete valid input strings:

[image: tab-complete validateset]

Comment: Another good suggestion, but I don't want my users to have to input a function name, arg name, and tab through 52 variables until they get what they want. I also want them to be able to see a full list they can use, and just pick the one they want.

Comment: You could use this and provide your users with the `PSReadLine`-module or Win10 (where it is preinstalled). Then they could write `userinputtest -userinput` and press ctrl+space to list the available values.